# Onclick is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Why will this code not work as an onclick ?

```
$('.mainz11').click (function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '280px'
    }, 800);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '100px'
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) only takes 1 handler function parameter, not 2. what are you trying to do? also, see [how accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to first expand the element and then contract it, it should probably be something like this:

```
$('.mainz11').click(function() {
    // determine target heights
    if ($(this).hasClass("expanded")) {
            var targetHeight = 100;
    } else {
        var targetHeight = 280;
    }

    // animate
    $(this).animate({
        height: targetHeight
    }, { 
        duration: 800,
        complete: function() { $(this).toggleClass("expanded"); }
    });
});
```

This could use some cleaning up, but it does the trick, and you can track expanded items easily this way.
See here: http://jsfiddle.net/mpQek/3/

Answer (score 0):

The [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function takes only a single function but you are passing 2 functions to it. You can try it this way:

```
 $('.mainz11').click (function() {
    $(this).animate({
    height: '280px'
    }, 800);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chain animations, put the next animation as the function to run on complete of the first animation:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
    $('.mainz11').click (function() { 
  $(this).animate({ height: '280px', 800, 
    function() { $('.mainz11').animate({ height: '100px'}, 800)
  ); 
 });
```